# Changing the tab bar title of the moreNavigationController from "More" to a custom

Tags: iphone, objective-c

is there a way to change the title in the tabbar of the moreNavigationController? It always shows "More". I tried it with setting the moreNavigationController.tabBarItem.title, unfortunately it seems to have to effect.

Sincerely,
Heinrich

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change UITabBarController More button's title?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918515/how-to-change-uitabbarcontroller-more-buttons-title)

Answer (score 1):

Sure there is:

Just do this:

```
self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Custom Title";
```

Comment: i believe the OP wants to change the title of the tab on the tab bar, not the title at the top of the more navigation controller

Answer (score -1):

To change **More** controller's title, you have to set title property by directly accessing its first view controller in the navigation stack:

```
self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.viewControllers[0].title = @"Custom Title";
```

I would not recommend changing navigation bar's `topItem` title directly, because this title will change when user navigates back and forth, and iOS will take title from corresponding controller's `title` property.